# Sending Emails with Gmail API

Tags: node.js, api, gmail

I'm currently working on hooking into the Gmail API using NodeJS. I have a working connection and can access my messages and such, but I'm having difficulty actually sending email with the API. Here is what I have below:

```
/**
 * Send Message.
 *
 * @param  {String} userId User's email address. The special value 'me'
 * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
 * @param  {String} email RFC 5322 formatted String.
 * @param  {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
 */
function sendMessage(userId, email, callback, auth) {
  // Using the js-base64 library for encoding:
  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-base64
  //var base64EncodedEmail = Base64.encodeURI(email);

  var base64EncodedEmail = Buffer.from(email).toString('base64');
  var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
    'userId': userId,
    'resource': {
      'raw': base64EncodedEmail
    }
  });
  request.execute(callback);
}
```

This is from the official documentation ([here)](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send), for the most part. I'm calling the function as such:

```
authorize(JSON.parse(content), sendMessage('me', btoa('This is a test')));
```

The error I'm getting is this:

> var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
>                   ^
>
> ReferenceError: gapi is not defined
>       at sendMessage (D:\Documents\Web Programming\React\neis-guy-painting\src\Server\Node\gmail.js:148:17)
>       at fs.readFile (D:\Documents\Web Programming\React\neis-guy-painting\src\Server\Node\gmail.js:23:34)
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)

I realize that this is because I don't have `gapi` defined, but I can't seem to figure out what that actually *should* be.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? Which do you want to use Javascript or Node.js? Because it seems that your script is for Javascript.